# Html create group rows and display rows side by side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap table have 30 rows. In the image below you can see it

[image]

This codes generates similar to the image above

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
        <tr>
          <td>@counter</td>
             @foreach (var Answer in item.Question.Answers))
             {
                <td style="border:1px solid #808080; border-radius:90px; width:30px; height:16px; text-align:center;">
                  <div>
                      /*Some Code*/
                  </div>
                </td>
              }
         </tr>
         counter++;
      }
      @if (Model.Count() < 30)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < 30 - Model.Count(); i++)
         {
            <tr>
              <td>@counter</td>
              <td>
                 <div style="border:1px solid #808080; border-radius:90px; width:30px; height:16px; text-align:center;">
                 </div>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <div style="border:1px solid #808080; border-radius:90px; width:30px; height:16px; text-align:center;">
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <div style="border:1px solid #808080; border-radius:90px; width:30px; height:16px; text-align:center;">
                  </div>
               </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="border:1px solid #808080; border-radius:90px; width:30px; height:16px; text-align:center;">
                  </div>
                </td>
           </tr>
           counter++;
         }
     }
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

I want the rows to look like the image below.

[image]

How can i do it ?

Comment: i think better if you show the code you use for create it

Comment: @corsaro I put the codes